# Finish app go back to last open app

Tags: android, android-launcher

I have an application that has a transparent background activity and with only a few buttons. When I switch to my application from another (using the button to switch between applications) I would like to keep the previous app visible in the background. Problem is that switching active app minimizes the previous one and is no longer visible.

Is it possible to do that? I realized that in the Play Store when I throw my request the background remains the Play Store.
Please get me out of my doubt if this is possible or not.

Reality: point 4 return home screen

[expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsVKi.png)

Comment: I want to be sure I understand correctly: you want to have the last open application still visible in the background when you open your app?

Comment: EXACTLY Maite Radu

Answer (score 0):

does this solve your riddle?

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View oView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_transperant, null);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
        0 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);        
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.addView(oView, params);
```

Comment: Not solve. The last open application still visible in the background when you open your app and not home screen.